# Multivariable local maximum proof

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization, quadratic-forms

Suppose we have a twice differentiable function $f: \mathbb{R} ^n \to \mathbb{R}$, a point ${\bf x^0} = (x_1 ^0 , \ldots , x_n ^0)$ and we know that

1. $\nabla f({\bf x}^0) = 0$
2. $({\bf x - x^0})H({\bf x^0})({\bf x - x^0})^T <0 $, $(H({\bf x^0})$ is the Hessian matrix of $f$)

Prove that $f({\bf x^0})$ is the local maximum of $f$.

**Attempt at a solution**

Since $\nabla f({\bf x}^0) = 0$ we know that ${\bf x^0}$ is a critical point of the function $f$. Because the Hessian is smaller than $0$ at the point ${\bf x^0}$, $f$ has a local maximum at the point ${\bf x^0}$.$\hspace{0.5em} \square$

Here is my dilemma. My "proof" feels very cheap. However, I'm not taking a proof heavy class (in fact proofs of why $f$ has a local maximum at a critical point if the Hessian is smaller than zero are not included in my text!) so I don't know what to add ... I feel like I have said everything that has to be said so I'm hoping any of you can point out to me how I can buff it up. I just want to add that this question isn't really homework, it's from an old final by my teacher which I'm solving in my free time. Thanks.

**Improved solution**

We know that $\nabla f({\bf x}^0) = 0$. Then, by definition, ${\bf x}^0$ is a critical point of $f$. Define function $g({\bf x}^0) = ({\bf x - x^0})H({\bf x^0})({\bf x - x^0})^T < 0$. Since $g({\bf x}^0) < 0$, all the eigenvalues of $H({\bf x^0})$ are less than $0$ resulting in $f$ having a local maximum at the point ${\bf x^0}$.

All there is left to do is reference where I use known theorems. Is this sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property 2 is a statement about a matrix, but in your proof, you say 'the Hessian is smaller than $0$'. This doesn't quite follow.

If you want some details to fill out, you can start there - assuming you know that "a critical point of $f$ is a maximum if the *determinant* of the Hessian is smaller than zero" how can you connect property 2 to a negative determinant?

If you *really* wanted to tear this apart, you could start from scratch, and prove "a critical point of $f$ is a maximum if the determinant of the Hessian is smaller than zero".

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have improved my solution and I was wondering if you could look it over.

Comment: Yeah, that looks good. As you say, you just need to fill in the missing 'known theorems' (quadratic form negative $\Leftarrow$ eigenvalues negative $\Leftarrow$ determinant negative) and you're set.

Comment: Shoot, I mean "quadratic form negative $\Rightarrow$ eigenvalues negative $\Rightarrow$ determinant negative". Can't tell left from right today, I guess.